# If I were to personify death is there a better statement than "delay death"

Tags: vocabulary

If I were to personify death is their a better statement then "delay death".  I have considered saying "negotiate with death" but that does not sound formal enough for the tone of my essay.

I am trying to express that science continues to negotiate with death in order to delay it. Preferably with a negative connotation.

I have considered "parley" however I dont know if that is the proper use for it nor if I should use it as "parley death" or "parley with death"

Comment: Do you mean a negative connotation as in, "science" should not be doing it?

Comment: *thwart*, *circumvent*?

Comment: Because you are talking about science, I suggest "outwit".

Comment: [Playing chess with death?](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0050976/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're personifying, or using a metaphor, then anything is appropriate because it's not meant to be interpreted literally, so long as it makes sense for the personification.

For example:

> I knocked chairs in Death's path, as he chased me.

Clearly knocking chairs over has nothing to do with the process of dying, but the statement makes sense because it makes sense in the context of the subject being a *person*.

As to whether the word you've used is effective for the meaning you're trying to express, that really depends on what imagery you're trying to express.

For example, in the example I've given, the imagery we're conjuring is dying being a *chase* where Death catches up with you.

Whereas you might be wanting to refer to death as a *struggle*, or perhaps as a *fine to pay*, or a *negotiation* or maybe death is an *unwelcome guest*. The words you choose to use will change the imagery, and it's up to you as the writer to decide what imagery you're wanting to use.

To answer your question - yes 'I parleyed with Death' makes sense, but there are also other words you could use.